# How to connect Elastic search 5.4 to tcp in java?

Tags: java, elasticsearch, tcp

Here is my java code to connect with tcp when I am using Elasticsearch version 1.7.2 and it works well but when I am using same code with Elasticsearch 5.4-3 it shows no definition of ImmutableSettings.

```
  Client client = null; 
    try { 
        Settings settings = ImmutableSettings.settingsBuilder()
                .put("client.transport.ignore_cluster_name", true) 
                .put("client.transport.sniff", false) 
                 .build(); 
   System.out.print("true");
         client = new TransportClient(settings) 
         .addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress("10.196.2.215", 9300));
 }
```

There is also no tcp settings in Elasticsearch 5.4-3/config/elasticserch.yml file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are major changes between the versions that you have specified in the question. If you want to create a connection successfully in the `5.4.3` version, refer the following code snippet.

```
import org.elasticsearch.action.get.GetResponse;
import org.elasticsearch.client.transport.TransportClient;
import org.elasticsearch.common.settings.Settings;
import org.elasticsearch.common.transport.InetSocketTransportAddress;
import org.elasticsearch.transport.client.PreBuiltTransportClient;

import java.net.InetAddress;
import java.net.UnknownHostException;

public class ElasticSearchClientTest {
    public void clientConnectionTest() throws UnknownHostException {

        // Use any settings here (As you mentioned in the code)
        Settings settings = Settings.builder()
                .put("cluster.name", "elasticsearch")
                .put("client.transport.sniff", true)
                .put("sniffOnConnectionFault", true).build();

        TransportClient client = new PreBuiltTransportClient(settings);

        // Change the ip address or the host name accordingly.
        client.addTransportAddress(new InetSocketTransportAddress(InetAddress.getByName("localhost"), 9300));
    }
}
```

Use following dependencies in the pom.xml file.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
    <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.3</version>
    <scope>compile</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: Thanks @Hiran for your comment...I have tried this but it gaves me following exception                                                                       "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/elasticsearch/client/transport/TransportClient : Unsupported major.minor version 52.0"

Comment: @user2778724 - this should be maven error, please remove all other elasticsearch dependencies from the pom.xml file and try it again.

Comment: @user2778724  - keep only elasticsearch dependencies which i have mention in the answer, remove all other elasticsearch related dependencies.

Comment: I have only these two dependensies my pom.xml is like     <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>1</groupId>
  <artifactId>1</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>firstproject</name>

Comment: <dependencies>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
    <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.3</version>
   </dependency>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
    <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.3</version>
   </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>

Comment: @user2778724 - What is your java version setup in the project?

Comment: You should have the java compiler plugin configured as mentioned in the below link (use java 1.8) : https://gist.github.com/torgeir/6742158

Comment: it is java-7-openjdk and I think so this is the problem although I have changed my ubuntu java version to Java 8 but dont know why eclipse is using Java 7

Comment: Yes, as i said use the compiler plugin as the link i provided and set the path variable to 1.8 jdk instead of 1.7

Comment: Thanks @user2778724  :)